# jQuery scrollLeft multiple steps

Tags: jquery

I am using Jquery scrollLeft like in this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/r6HwL/7/).

How can I change the 'next' click to scroll 3 images to the right(and left) instead on just one?

```
var $boxes = $(".images"),
    $slides = $('#slides'),
    pos = 0;
$("#next").click(function () {
    var $nextBox = $boxes.first();
    $boxes.length > ++pos + 3 ? $nextBox = $($boxes[pos]) : pos = 0;
    $slides.animate({
        scrollLeft: $nextBox.offset().left + $slides.scrollLeft()
    }, 500);
});
$("#prev").click(function () {
    var $nextBox = $boxes.last();
    ($boxes.length > --pos && pos > -3) ? $nextBox = $($boxes[pos]) : pos = $boxes.length - 3;
    $slides.animate({
        scrollLeft: $nextBox.offset().left + $slides.scrollLeft()
    }, 500);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#next").click(function () {
    var $nextBox = $boxes.first();

    pos += 3;
    $boxes.length > pos ? $nextBox = $($boxes[pos]) : pos = 0;

    $slides.animate({
        scrollLeft: $nextBox.offset().left + $slides.scrollLeft()
    }, 500);
});

$("#prev").click(function () {
    var $nextBox = $boxes.last();

    pos -= 3;
    ($boxes.length > pos && pos > -1) ? $nextBox = $($boxes[pos]) : pos = $boxes.length - 3;

    $slides.animate({
        scrollLeft: $nextBox.offset().left + $slides.scrollLeft()
    }, 500);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/r6HwL/89/

Answer (score 1):

I have updated your Javascript to look like this, you can see this on JS Fiddle. I would also recommend refactoring the code so that the animate functionality is wrapped in its own function.

Also, be aware that index of 0 is the first slide, 1 is the second slide, and so on.

http://jsfiddle.net/r6HwL/86/

```
var $boxes = $(".images"),
    $slides = $('#slides'),
    pos = 0;
$('button[data-go]').on('click', function() {
    var slide = $('input[data-slide]').val(),
        el = $slides.find('img').eq(slide);

    $slides.animate({
        scrollLeft: el.offset().left + $slides.scrollLeft()
    }, 500);
});


$("#next").click(function () {
    var $nextBox = $boxes.first();

    $boxes.length > ++pos ? $nextBox = $($boxes[pos]) : pos = 0;

    $slides.animate({
        scrollLeft: $nextBox.offset().left + $slides.scrollLeft()
    }, 500);
});

$("#prev").click(function () {
    var $nextBox = $boxes.last();

    ($boxes.length > --pos && pos > -1) ? $nextBox = $($boxes[pos]) : pos = $boxes.length - 1;

    $slides.animate({
        scrollLeft: $nextBox.offset().left + $slides.scrollLeft()
    }, 500);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

My (late) bit has configurable steps.

```
var $boxes = $(".images"),
    $slides = $('#slides'),
    pos = 0;
    mx = $boxes.length;
    steps = 3;

$("#next").click(function () {
    pos = pos + steps;
    if (pos >= mx) {
        pos = 0;
    }
    var $nextBox = $boxes.eq(pos);
    $slides.animate({
        scrollLeft: $nextBox.offset().left + $slides.scrollLeft()
    }, 500);
});

$("#prev").click(function () {
    pos = pos - steps;
    if (pos < 0) {
        pos = mx - steps;
    }
    var $nextBox = $boxes.eq(pos);
    $slides.animate({
        scrollLeft: $nextBox.offset().left + $slides.scrollLeft()
    }, 500);
});
```